# How to check at function call if default keyword arguments are used

Tags: python, default, keyword-argument

I`m working on some initialization function/method which should
warn you if the default values are used for the kwargs. I can't
figure out how to do so and google did not help me either. 
Any solutions?

To illustrate

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(a=0,b=1):
        ''' Should warn you if using default.'''
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
```

Should act as follows

```
MyClass(a=1)
>>> 'warning: default b=1 is used.
```

Why would one want the warning: Defualts are there to illustrate the typical values used. However the end user should set  them and not be lazy(!). End user manipulates yamls with kwargs: make end user aware if he/she messes up. Basically I want the (soft) requiredness of args with all the benefits of kwargs.

Comment: Could you explain why you would need to warn about defaults? If they are defaults I think the function should just perform as normal without warning.

Comment: Should there be a warning if someone calls `MyClass(0, 1)`?

Comment: Well.. the user awareness is always a good thing, and if the user knows that a specific default value is used if not specifically defined looks extremely interesting.
This could also be useful in a situation where the second value changes, if not specified, based on the first argument values..

Comment: @Rawing I guess no but I'd rather have the kwargs passed in an explicit manner

Comment: @shakabra added an explanation to the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kwargs` in `__init__` for the warnings and then a dedicated `initialize` function for the assignment of the variables:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = dict(a=0, b=1)
        for key,val in defaults.items():
            if key not in kwargs:
                print("warning: default {}={} is used.".format(key, val))
            kwargs[key]=val

        self.initialize(**kwargs)

    def initialize(self, a=0, b=1):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

MyClass()
print('-'*50)
MyClass(a=5)
print('-'*50)
MyClass(a=4,b=3)
```

The output is:

```
warning: default b=1 is used.
warning: default a=0 is used.
--------------------------------------------------
warning: default b=1 is used.
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like a good general approach. A bit verbose with the double definition of default values but that is something you probably cant do without in the language.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if not 'b' in kwargs:
            print "warning"
        self._a = kwargs.get('a', 0)
        self._b = kwargs.get('b', 1)
```

This code uses the "get" function of a dictionary that extract the value stored in the key (that is the first argument) and, if the keys does not exists, fallback on the second argument that is the "default" value.

Don't know if this could be of some help?

[Python 2.7 "get" function for a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

---

## Update

Because the answer from Thomas Kuhn was extremely interesting, I wanted to push it even further:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = dict(a=0, b=1)
        for key, value in defaults.iteritems():
            if not key in kwargs:
                print "Warning: default {0}={1} is used.".format(key, value)
            kwargs.setdefault(key, value)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

m = MyClass()
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30

m = MyClass(a=10)
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30

m = MyClass(a=10, b=11)
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30
```

This way you can have two main advantages:

- Your attribute list will be added directly into the class as parameter so you can access it.
- The `setdefault` method extract the value if the key exists, and if not simply add the key with the default value specified.

---

I understand that this code could be extremely dangerous in a non controlled environment, so you can eventually fallback on a more complex structure for your class, using the methods:

- `__getattr__(self, attributename)` for extracting the attribute value based on the name defined, so that you can keep all your values inside a local variable like self.classparameters or something
- `__setattr__(self, attributename, attributevalue)` for setting the value.

And this is the code:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = dict(a=0, b=1)
        for key, value in defaults.iteritems():
            if not key in kwargs:
                print "Warning: default {0}={1} is used.".format(key, value)
            kwargs.setdefault(key, value)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, parameter):
        return self.__dict__.get(parameter)

    def __setattr__(self, parameter, value):
        self.__dict__.update({parameter: value})

m = MyClass()
m.b = 11
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30

m = MyClass(a=10)
m.b = 101
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30

m = MyClass(a=10, b=11)
m.b = 1001
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30
```

This is something that needs to be handheld with extreme care because you could (and will) have some serious issues in multiple situations.

> Alert: this is *not* an explanation on how to use `__setattr__` and `__getattr__`, instead is a simple (and stupid) way to approach the same problem with multiple solutions, so if you know how to improve this bit with a more smart way of using those *magic methods*, you're welcome.

---

Another way of implementing this process, that could be more verbose, but lets you have A LOT of control of what happens is using the decorator @property:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.classparam = dict(a=0, b=1)
        for key, value in self.classparam.iteritems():
            if not key in kwargs:
                print "Warning: default {0}={1} is used.".format(key, value)
            kwargs.setdefault(key, value)
        self.classparam.update(kwargs)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.classparam.get('a')

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self.classparam.update(a=value)

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.classparam.get('b')

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self.classparam.update(b=value)

m = MyClass()
m.b = 10
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30

m = MyClass(a=10)
m.b = 100
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30

m = MyClass(a=10, b=11)
m.b = 1000
print "a: {0}; b: {1}".format(m.a, m.b)
print "-"*30
```

Comment: I like this solution! It's very to the point. Would be great for a small number of kwargs. Thomas Kühn's answer would work in a more general case.

Comment: Thank you for another inspiring suggestion. I was previously unaware of the setdefault method! See my answer for what I eventually came up with.

Comment: @balletpiraat, you're welcome! Actually you inspired my with some improvement to my parameter checks in my workflow :)

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually came up with -- with the help of a colleague -- is to use a class attribute to store the defaults:

To illustrate:

```
class MySpecialClass():

    default_kwargs = dict(a=0,b=0)

    def __init__(self,kwargs):

        _kwargs = do_something(kwargs,self.default_kwargs)

        self.a = _kwargs['a']
        ... some more unpacking ... 

instance = MySpecialClass({'a':0})
>>> some effect
```

where `do_something()` fills in missing keys/raises warnings etc.

To me this has all I want:

- explicit about default value
- simple, uses no un-obvious language features
- explicit unpacking -- you get an error if there is still something missing.
- flexible/clean via `do_something()`
- more?

Comment: mmh.. you could still use `**kwargs`, because the way you are using it, is not obvious, but require always a parameter to be passed to the constructor. What happen with `**kwargs` instead is a more pythonic way of let the constructor (or any other function or method) to have the parameters passed as: `MyClass(a=12,b='asd')` that could be a more comprehensive way of working with an object.